# TCP Sampler in JMeter

Tags: tcp, jmeter

I am using TCP Sampler in JMeter. The data being sent is in the HEX format (45 00 0F CD 04 39 40 00)and JMeter is unable to process the data. On execution, JMeter throws a read exception.

The Read Exception obtained is : meter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler:  org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPClientImpl.read(TCPClientImpl.java:117)

Please guide me on the same if anyone of you have used TCP Sampler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send your data without spaces 45000FCD04394000, and check if you use TCP Sampler properly in order with instructions from http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler